# I want to concatinate two keys from different two dictionary in python

Tags: python

```
dic1 = {'Cy':[{'ONE':[2334566576576876867867866866868883322342342, 553134327472378448284]},{'THREE':[567832342342478624627364236462342, 72734682736472634782847], 'Cyp':[{'TWO':[2356252323232327686786786556546456462, 55232453454]},{'FOUR':[567832342342478624627364236462342, 727344564564562342]}
dic2 = {'Cy':[{'FIVE':[2898454387598345923131231231213, 598237494943543500213213034]}
```

I used the following code

```
dict3 = {}
for key in (dic1.keys() | dic2.keys()):
     if key in dic1: dict3.setdefault(key, []).append(dic1[key])
     if key in dic2: dict3.setdefault(key, []).append(dic2[key])
print result
```

Unfortunately i got an error saying

> Not all arguments converted during string formatting

Is any one find a way to concatenate two keys in dictionary and keep the original values without changing since I will use these value for decryption?

Comment: The code provided can not produce that error message. Maybe something else in your code is producing that error?

Comment: @Artyer .  I used dict3 = dict(dict1, **dict2) instead. but it is not working because it does not take all Cy for dict1 and put it to Cy in dict2 which means dict3 have only Cy of dict2 only then Cy of dict1 is missing. is there is way to fix that please ?

Answer (score 0):

Your dicts have a bunch of tags and array tags lefted open.
`result` isnt a variable then you have declared before, maybe your print statement must be chaged to `print dict3`.